can a solana wallet address have restrictions that disable SPL Token functionality?
I would like to know if it is possible to effectively turn off the ability for a wallet address to receive SPL Tokens...To put it another way- have the wallet only recieve native SOL. Is there a way to disable    "spl-token create-account"  at a wallet address ? A potential use case would be for a wallet address at a centralized exchange to only recieve native SOL... ensuring users do not send an unsupported asset to the exchange wallet address... which would result in loss of user funds... Any info would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Unfortunately, directly disabling spl-token create-account at a wallet address on Solana isn't possible. Solana operates on a permissionless model, meaning anyone can send any type of token to any address. However, a workaround would be for these exchanges to monitor any receipt of unsupported tokens and send it back to the original sender. also
Clear Documentation and User Education(which most already do)w:CEXes could have clear documentation outlining supported deposit tokens. This includes specifying the exact wallet address for SOL deposits and highlighting the potential loss of unsupported tokens sent to the exchange address.
